# How to exclude just one chapter number in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to add an appendix to the end of my thesis. But I don't want LaTeX to enumerate that section as a chapter in the table of contents.

Do you know how I can get it without numbering? I don't want that number 5 in the table of contents!

BTW, I use book document style.

[image]

Comment: Are you using `\chapter{Appendix 1}` to include the appendix? If so, use `\chapter*{Appendix 1} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix 1}` instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `\chapter*` is sufficient to remove numbering of the content in the ToC and in the chapter title. You'll have to manually insert a ToC-entry, as well as update the headers, if possible:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]

\appendix
\chapter*{Appendix 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix 1}% Add Appendix to ToC
\markboth{APPENDIX 1}{APPENDIX 1}% Correct headers

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

`\backmatter` should be sufficient to suppress the addition of numbers in the `ToC`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}

\backmatter
\appendix

\chapter{Appendix Stuff}


\end{document}
```

[image]