# I want to remove one chapter title from the beginning of the chapter, but keep all the others

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I want to remove "Chapter 5" from the beginning of the chapter. But I just want to do that for one chapter, while I keep all the others.

Do you know how to do that?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t understand: isn’t this an exact duplicate of [another question of yours](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319279/69818)?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: Technically no, since the other question was focused around the ToC. This requests an update of the chapter title. Realistically, yes, a single question describing the problem in more detail would have yielded a single answer that covered both cases...

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti no, it's not! That is about the table of contents, but this is inside the chapter!!

Comment: [Christian Hupfer’s answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319282/69818) solves both problems at once.  It is conceptually wrong to treat the two aspects as two distinct problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `\chapter*`. Some other modification are also needed in order to place the appendix in the ToC (if needed) and update the headers:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]

\appendix
\chapter*{Appendix 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix 1}% Add Appendix to ToC
\markboth{APPENDIX 1}{APPENDIX 1}% Correct headers

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure the headers are “correct”.

Comment: @egreg: Yes. Choose them accordingly...